# A/B Test statistics

Tags: statistics, ab-testing, abtest

I am trying to do some statistical analysis of different A/B tests to see which alternative is better and have found conflicting information about this.

First, I am interested in a couple different things:

- Tests that measure success by counting events, such as conversions or emails sent
- Tests that measure success by counting revenue
- Tests that have only two alternatives (control and new)
- Tests that have multiple alternatives (control and multiple new)

I was hoping to find a simple set of formulae or rules for doing this analysis but have found more questions than answers.

[This site](http://blog.asmartbear.com/easy-statistics-for-adwords-ab-testing-and-hamsters.html) says that you can't compare multi-alternative tests; you can only do pairwise comparisons and do a chi-squared analysis to see if the whole test is statistically significant or not.

[This site](http://elem.com/~btilly/effective-ab-testing/) Suggests a way to do A/B/C/D testing (starts on slide 74), analysing the results using the G-Test (which it says is related to chi-squared) but isn't clear on the details of using a fudge factor.  It also suggests that you can only use the A/B/C/D approach to eliminate alternatives until you end up with a clear winner in an A/B comparison.

[This site](http://20bits.com/articles/statistical-analysis-and-ab-testing/) gives an example of an A/B/C/D test (including control) and shows how to compare the conversion rate to determine a winner.  Unlike [this approach](http://elem.com/~btilly/effective-ab-testing/) it does not recommend eliminating alternatives but rather picks a winner right off the bat (Assuming statistically significant results).

Perhaps I'm naive but I would think that by now a stats analysis library would exist to deal with this very problem.  I would also appreciate more information about what algorithms/equations are needed to solve these problems.  It's been a long time since my university Stats class.

Comment: You might also ask this over on http://mathoverflow.net

Comment: mathoverflow (according to the FAQ) is for mathematicians talking to mathematicians.  Not sure if it's the right place.

Answer (score 1):

For the event generating comparison, you could approach this using [Beta distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).  Each alternative has some unobserved *p*, the probability of producing an event.  If you observe *X* positive events out of *N*, then your uncertainty about *p* can be modeled by *Beta(X+1,N-X+1)*.

You can compare two alternatives by looking at *P(pA > pB)*, where *pA* and *pB* are the two Beta distributions.  Methods for computing that inequality probability can be found in this [paper](http://www.bepress.com/mdandersonbiostat/paper54).

You can also compute E[pA-pB], the effect size, or compute confidence bounds of the same.

Comment: Also, you might watch this blog (the next post is supposed to be on this subject): http://sirevanhaas.com/?p=30

Comment: And you might read chapter 37 of this book: http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/itila/book.html

Individual chapters are available here: http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/itprnn/ps/